# Clickhouse backup failure - Table has its shared ID to be different from one from the create query

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

In a clickhouse 3 shard, 3 replica setup, I am trying to take a schema backup.
But it fails with following error :

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE default 
TO S3( 'https://bucket-id.s3.amazonaws.com/backup_folder/snapshot_2023_10_30_schema' ) 
SETTINGS structure_only=true ASYNC

-- Later check the status of the backup

SELECT * FROM system.backups WHERE id = 'query-id' \G
```

We observe following error

```
Code: 49. 
DB::Exception: Table {} has its shared ID to be different from one from the create query: 
While collecting tables for backup in database default. (LOGICAL_ERROR) 
(version 23.6.2.18 (official build))
```

Few questions :

- How can we resolve this schema issue & bring it to stable state ?
- It is also not showing which particular table is causing the issue. Is there a way to know which table is causing the issue. May be, we don't need that particular table.
- Now such a state blocks the schema backup of whole database. Is there a way to skip and continue with other tables

Comment: Is the database a Replicated?  Os is this a single node Atomic DB?

Comment: It's an Atomic database in a clickhouse cluster

Comment: is error message contains table name or just empty {}?

Comment: did you check /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log for related time range?

Comment: @Slach error message didn't contain table name. it's as shown above

Comment: try `grep -c 10 -i backup /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log`
and ensure you have trace logging level in /etc/clickhouse-server/